# A figurative use of "exclamation point"

Tags: meaning, idioms

I was reading a [news article](http://www.espn.com/olympics/gymnastics/story/_/id/17276697/2016-summer-olympics-simone-biles-united-states-finishes-first-gymnastics-all-around) about Simone Biles and found a sentence that I'm not sure I understand correctly:

> Biles earned her first gold on Tuesday while serving as the exclamation point to retiring national team coordinator Martha Karolyi's going away party.

The problem is the figurative use of "exclamation point".

I spent some time on googling and have two hypotheses:

1. It is a reference to "Cross all t's and dot all i's and exclamation points", meaning a "finishing touch", "finali";
2. An exclamation mark at the end of her career, as if the career is a sentence. That is not just a dull point, but something bright as an exclamation mark.

Am I right? Or is there something trivial that I missed?

Thank you.

Comment: Number one and number two are essentially the same and you need both to understand it completely. To use your own words, it *is* as if the team coordinator's career had been "a sentence" and it had not only ended, but had ended with a "finishing touch, a finale," as denoted by the exclamation mark.

Comment: And this is from a professional news article, so I'm assuming it has been edited, but personally, I would have just said, "...on Tuesday, serving..." and I would not have included the "while," which, I think, is part of where the confusion stems from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting the general idea. I'd say that *exclamation point* in this context is similar to the idiom *icing on the cake*, which, according to [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+icing+on+the+cake), means "something that makes a good situation even better."

This figurative and adjectival use of "exclamation point" is often used by sportscasters and sportswriters, referring to something that happened near the end of a game to either assure a win for the eventual victor, or (perhaps more commonly) to add some late scoring at the end of rout. Here are a few usages I found using [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/exclamation-point) and Google:

> Collison had the most memorable moment, diving on the floor to rip the ball away from Chris Bosh and set up a jumper by Westbrook that extended the lead to 85-81. Jeff Green followed that **with an exclamation-point dunk** with [33.8](http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/sports/scores108/108354/NBA837059.htm) seconds left for a six-point lead, and that cemented the win.
>
> [Recapping a [5-0 win](http://www.dailylocal.com/article/DL/20090924/NEWS01/309249956)] Morgan Daugherty added **an exclamation point goal** for Henderson off of a free kick with 1:50 remaining.
>
> McAuliffe offered little in the way of sympathy for her Beanpot brethren, hoisting the puck over Davis for **an exclamation-point goal** with just five seconds left. The [7-2 victory](http://news.harvard.edu/gazette/story/2002/02/beanpot-stays-put/) marks Harvard’s 8th Beanpot title.
>
> Farrah then burst thru the left side and broke outside and rolled 23-yards for **an exclamation point touchdown** to make it [26-7](http://www.thegraftonnews.com/articles/were-going-to-gillette/) with just under four and a half minutes to go.

Comment: Thank you! I noticed that usage too but then rejected it because the context is not about a breakaway. But now I see that the author might describe the career in sports terms as well.

Comment: Yes; while it's often used in the context of a game, it can be extended and be used to talk about a triumphant moment at the end of a successful career, too.